# Drag breakdown of a typical civil airplane wing

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, drag

How much of the drag produced by a typical GA/airliner/cargo plane's wing at cruise is induced, frictional, and pressure drag?

Comment: Induced drag is mainly due to [pressure drag](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/98890/what-is-viscous-induced-drag/98900#98900). It'd be more correct to ask how much is induced and how much is parasite

Answer (score 4):

At best L/D, an aircraft (with a simple parabolic polar) has half induced and half parasite drag.

If half the parasite drag is from the fuselage -- and you are flying at best L/D, then we can say that of the total drag:

25% fuselage parasite
25% wing parasite
50% induced

Or, of just the wing

33% parasite
66% induced

You likely aren't cruising exactly at best L/D.  And you will have other components that contribute to the parasite drag of the aircraft.  But this should give you a reasonable idea of how to make a starting estimate.